# How to define component/step using training operators such as TFJob in kubeflow pipeline

Tags: kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I know there is a way to use tfjob operator via kubectl, like the example at here (https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/training/tftraining/):

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubeflow/training-operator/master/examples/tensorflow/simple.yaml
```

But I don't know how to incorporate in kubeflow pipeline. A normal component/job is defined via @component decoration or ContainerOp is a Kubernetes ***Job*** kind which runs in a Pod, but I don't know how to define a component with special training operator such as ***TFJob***, so that my code runs as

```
apiVersion: "kubeflow.org/v1"
kind: TFJob
```

rather than:

```
apiVersion: "kubeflow.org/v1"
kind: Job
```

in kubernetes.

P.S.: there is a example here: https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/master/components/kubeflow/launcher/sample.py
but don't see anywhere specify ***TFJob***

Answer (score 1):

The example you reference leverages some code that actually creates a TFJob ([look at the folder of your example](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/tree/master/components/kubeflow/launcher/src)):

- TFJob is instantiated here: https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/master/components/kubeflow/launcher/src/launch_tfjob.py#L97
- ...and created as Kubernetes resource here: https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/master/components/kubeflow/launcher/src/launch_tfjob.py#L126
- ...the previous code is accessed by a Kubeflow component as specified here: https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/master/components/kubeflow/launcher/component.yaml
- ...which is imported into your referenced example here: https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/master/components/kubeflow/launcher/sample.py#L60

The general question you raised is still subject to [current discussions](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/issues/677). Using `tfjob_launcher_op` appears to be the currently recommended way. Instead, some people also natively use `ResourceOps` to simulate your `kubectl create` call.